# Conflict with same library but with different versions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have my own project using the appcompat library:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

And my project uses a library which use:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
```

So Android Studio rises an error about this conflict. But I have no choice in my project than using the latest version of compat, and keep the library using the old one.

How is it possible to merge both? I already tried to exclude module like this:

```
implementation('com.azquidk.sdk') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
}
```

But doesn't work.

**EDIT**

In the meantime I found this which works too:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Step by step, I had to do this to make it work
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${libraries.google}")
            force ("com.android.support:design:${libraries.google}")
            force ("com.android.support:support-v13:${libraries.google}")
        }
    }
Thanks @shmakova